# Morphia: Filter element in ArrayList using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a Java class called Project with a `users` `ArrayList<User>` property that contains User objects.

My projects collection looks like

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56410150d277de02f3b67495"),
    "name" : "my-project",
    "users" : [ 
      {
        "id" : "58b5eb81-35b2-4719-87ad-e5eea76a478f",
        "name" : "john",
        "lastName" : "Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find a user with a specific UUID inside this property. I can find it in MongoDB with the following query:
`db.getCollection('projects').find({"users.id": "58b5eb81-35b2-4719-87ad-e5eea76a478f"})`

How do I get the same results using Morphia?

I've tried this:

```
Project project = datastore.createQuery(Project.class).filter("users.id", user_id).get();
```

And this:

```
Project project = datastore.find(Project.class, "users.id", user_id).get();
```

But with no luck :(

Any help?

I expect getting:

```
{
        "id" : "58b5eb81-35b2-4719-87ad-e5eea76a478f",
        "name" : "john",
        "lastName" : "Doe"
}
```

Comment: Can you possibly edit your question to include some sample data in the `projects` collection, the results of the find query and your expected output?

Comment: I've included more info in the question. I get no results when I try to query using Morphia

Comment: Thanks for updating, that's much better and more clear now!

Comment: Interesting that the first query doesn't work. But let's debug the actual query: `Query<Project> query = datastore.createQuery(Project.class).filter("users.id", user_id); LOG.debug(query.toString()); Project project = query.get();`

Comment: I'd also make sure `Project` is mapped to the `projects` collection.